# Find all yaml keys matching string and change their values using python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I've been trying to...

1. load yaml file
2. find all keys named "top" in a yaml file
3. get the values one by one, which is a percentage
4. add 5 to the percentage number
5. save the file

So far I've written the following python:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml
import re

in_file = Path('overview.yaml')
out_file = Path('new_overview.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(in_file)

#Found this in some other thread
def lookup(sk, d, path=[]):
   # lookup the values for key(s) sk return as list the tuple (path to the value, value)
   if isinstance(d, dict):
       for k, v in d.items():
           if k == sk:
               yield (path + [k], v)
           for res in lookup(sk, v, path + [k]):
               yield res
   elif isinstance(d, list):
       for item in d:
           for res in lookup(sk, item, path + [item]):
               yield res

#For each found result
for path, value in lookup("top", data):

    #Remove the percentage sign
    cleanvalue = re.sub('%','', value)

    #Convert to fload and add 5
    addvalue = float(cleanvalue) + 5

    #Print old and new value
    print(cleanvalue, addvalue)


#with open('husoversigt_changed.yaml', 'wb') as f:
#  yaml.dump(data, f)
```

So now it just prints the old value and the new value.

But I'm really struggling to change the "data" variable using the path found and returned by lookup function.

Can anyone help me?

A little piece of the data are here:

```
type: custom:mod-card
card:
  type: vertical-stack
  cards:
    - type: picture-elements
      elements:
        - type: state-icon
          entity: light.zigbee_bedroom_light
          tap_action:
            action: more-info
          style:
            top: 31%
            left: 74%
        - type: state-icon
          entity: binary_sensor.zigbee_mailbox_on_off
          tap_action:
            action: more-info
          style:
            top: 3%
            left: 42%
        - type: state-icon
          entity: group.alarm_sensors
          tap_action:
            action: more-info
          style:
            top: 20%
            left: 48%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursive `lookup` function yields the path and the value, so
you would have to use the path to traverse starting with `data`.

In your case it is probably easier to yield `d` and `v` instead:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

file_in = Path('overview.yaml')
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(file_in)

def lookup(sk, d, path=[]):
   # lookup the values for key(s) sk return as list the tuple (path to the value, value)
   if isinstance(d, dict):
       for k, v in d.items():
           if k == sk:
               yield (d, v)
           for res in lookup(sk, v, path + [k]):
               yield res
   elif isinstance(d, list):
       for item in d:
           for res in lookup(sk, item, path + [item]):
               yield res

for d, value in lookup("top", data):
    # remove the percentage sign
    value = value.replace('%', '')
    # don't make it a float if it isn't already a float
    if '.' in value:
        perc = float(value) + 5.0
    else:
        perc = int(value) + 5
    d['top'] = f'{perc}%'

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
type: custom:mod-card
card:
  type: vertical-stack
  cards:
  - type: picture-elements
    elements:
    - type: state-icon
      entity: light.zigbee_bedroom_light
      tap_action:
        action: more-info
      style:
        top: 36%
        left: 74%
    - type: state-icon
      entity: binary_sensor.zigbee_mailbox_on_off
      tap_action:
        action: more-info
      style:
        top: 8%
        left: 42%
    - type: state-icon
      entity: group.alarm_sensors
      tap_action:
        action: more-info
      style:
        top: 25%
        left: 48%
```